# Can one easily 'plug-in' an existing credentials repository to use when authenticating users on a DotNetNuke web site?

Tags: mysql, authentication, dotnetnuke

Can one easily 'plug-in' an existing credentials repository to use when authenticating users on a DotNetNuke web site and can we then take advantage of the DNN authorization framework?

More specifically: we have a database of user credentials (mySql) used to authenticate users. We're investigating using DNN for a new web site but are restricted to using the existing credentials repository. We can easily make the repository accessible but will we need to do any 'tweaking in the MS-Sql database that DNN uses etc?

Btw, am complete DNN newbie and just investigating feasability.

Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DotNetNuke has an [authentication provider](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Authentication_Providers.aspx) and membership provider, both of which you would probably need to implement to be able to use a separate database for credentials (though if it's *just* for credentials, you would just write an authentication provider to check that database upon login, then user regular DNN users for the membership part, if you're not pulling profile info from there).

Answer (score 1):

As Brian Dukes mentioned there is a provider model that makes this really easy.  And I might be able to get your 99% of the way there.  I have a commercial product [External Database Authentication Provider](http://www.iowacomputergurus.com/products/external-database-auth-provider.aspx) that connects to any external SQL Server for this type of thing.  Now it only communicates to SQL Server, but you can either grab the source and make 2-3 changes and be set, or I know other users in the past have actually created a SP in SQL Server that went to MySQL and used my module as is.

Comment: Thanks for feedback Michael. Will certainly take a closer look at your product.